# Does LLC Protect from Personal Lawsuit

Tags: legal, llc

I am looking on taking my first job as a freelance developer and the project involves ecommerce. We are starting to get to the contract talks and I wanted to make sure if anything goes horrible wrong in the event of hacking or loss of money from their store being down. I am not open to be sued personal and have my personal assets at risk. If I created an LLC for my freelance work would this protect me from losing an personal assets in the case of a lawsuit?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a legal question, not a freelance question. You may do better asking at law.stackexchange.com where legal professionals hang out.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, yes, unless you are found guilty of some crime or gross wrongdoing related to the claims in the lawsuit.  The liability would be limited to the assets of the LLC; hence the expression "limited liability company".

I am not an attorney.